# "pygame.error: No video mode has been set" even after pygame.display.set_mode has been assigned

Tags: python, pygame

I've done research on this error and it seems all the solutions lie in needing to do something like "screen = pygame.display.set_mode(x, y)", which I've done, however the video mode error still occurs.

further research just shows that the solution lies in adding a line of code I've already implemented. I've tried moving the location to within the loop which plays when my game is being ran, however I cannot seem to get it working.

here is my full code. the "screen = set_mode" code is found on line 11 and screen.blit on line 222

```
import pygame
import time

progress = 0

pygame.init()
(width, height) = (600, 400) #specify window resolution
background = pygame.image.load("spacebackground.png").convert()
bgx  = 0
bgy = 0
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height)) #create window
pygame.display.set_caption('EduGame') #specify window name

player_path = "downChara.png" #specifies image path


class Player(object): #representitive of the player's overworld sprite
        def __init__(self):
            self.image = pygame.image.load(player_path).convert_alpha() #creates image, the player_path variable allowing it to be updated
            self.X = (width/2) -16; # x co-ord of player
            self.Y = (height/2)-16; # y co-ord of player
            self.width = self.image.get_width()
            self.height = self.image.get_height()
            self.hitbox = (self.X, self.Y, self.width, self.height)


        def handle_keys(self, up, down, left, right): #handling the keys/inputs
                key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
                dist = 3 #distance travelled in one frame of the program
                if key[pygame.K_DOWN] and down == True: #if down
                        self.Y += dist #move down the length of dist
                        player_path = "downChara.png" #change image to down
                        self.image = pygame.image.load(player_path).convert_alpha()
                elif key[pygame.K_UP] and up == True: #if up
                        self.Y -= dist #move up the length of dist
                        player_path = "upChara.png" #change to up
                        self.image = pygame.image.load(player_path).convert_alpha()
                if key[pygame.K_RIGHT] and right == True: #etc.
                        self.X += dist
                        player_path = "rightChara.png"
                        self.image = pygame.image.load(player_path).convert_alpha()
                elif key[pygame.K_LEFT] and left == True:
                        self.X -= dist
                        player_path = "leftChara.png"
                        self.image = pygame.image.load(player_path).convert_alpha()


        def outX(coord): #"coord" acts the same as "self"
                return (coord.X)
        def outY(coord):
                return (coord.Y)


        def draw(self, surface): #draw to the surface/screen
            surface.blit(self.image, (self.X, self.Y))
            #pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), self.hitbox, 2)
            return self.X, self.Y, self.width, self.height


class NPC(object):      #NPC class
        def __init__(self, path, x, y,text):
                self.image = pygame.image.load(path).convert_alpha()
                self.x = x
                self.y = y
                self.width = self.image.get_width()
                self.height = self.image.get_height()
                self.hitbox = (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)
                self.text = text


        def spawn(self, surface): #NPC spawn location
                surface.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))
                self.hitbox = (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)
                #pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), self.hitbox, 2)

        def collide(self, x, y, width, height): #collision with player character
                key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
                othery = self.y + self.height
                otherx = self.x + self.width
                upperx = otherx - self.width/10
                lowerx = self.x + self.width/10
                #uppery = self.y + self.height/10
                #lowery = othery - self.height/10
                if self.y <= y <= othery and self.x <= x <= otherx or self.y <= y + height <= othery and self.x <= x <= otherx or self.y <= y <= othery and self.x <= x + width <= otherx or self.y <= y + height <= othery and self.x <= x + width <= otherx:
                       if key[pygame.K_RETURN]:
                               setup(self.text)
#older code:
                #if phitbox == self.hitbox:
##                        if uppery <= y <= othery: #toggles if you're touching an entity or not
##                                self.touchEntityBelow = True
##                                print("up")
##                        else:
##                                self.touchEntityBelow = False
##                        if self.y <= y <= lowery: #etc
##                                self.touchEntityAbove = True
##                                print("down")
##                        else:
##                                self.touchEntityAbove = False
##                        if upperx <= x <= otherx:
##                                self.touchEntityRight = True
##                                print("right")
##                        else:
##                                self.touchEntityRight = False
##                        if self.x <= x <= lowerx:
##                                self.touchEntityLeft = True
##                                print("left")
##                        else:
##                                self.touchEntityLeft = False
##                else:
##                        self.touchEntityRight = False
##                        self.touchEntityLeft = False
##                        self.touchEntityAbove = False
##                        self.touchEntityBelow = False
##        def grabValues(self, x, y):
##                return self.touchEntityBelow, self.touchEntityAbove, self.touchEntityLeft, self.touchEntityRight

def text_objects(text, font): #code for rendering the text in the colour and font
        textSurface = font.render(text, True, (255, 255, 255))
        return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def interact(text): #code for blitting text to screen, specifies font and textbox.
        textbox = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("bigbox.png"), (600, 111))
        textSize = pygame.font.Font("cour.ttf",28) #specify text size
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, textSize) #allow text to be positioned
        TextRect.topleft = (12, 297) #where text will be
        screen.blit(textbox, (0, 289))
        screen.blit(TextSurf, TextRect) #display text
        pygame.display.update() #updates screen
        time.sleep(2)
        screen.blit(background, TextRect)

def playerMove(posX, posY, width, height):
        if posX > width - 32: #this is because the sprite's "X" is determined in the top left corner, meaning we have to subtract the width from the measurement
                moveRight = False #following selection loops determine if the player can move. may need to be moved into the collision code so it does not intervene with NPC
                                  #collisions
        else:
                moveRight = True
        if posX < 0:
                moveLeft = False
        else:
                moveLeft = True
        if posY > height - 32: #this is because the sprite's "Y" is determined in the top left corner, meaning we have to subtract the width from the measurement
                moveDown = False
        else:
                moveDown = True
        if posY < 0:
                moveUp = False
        else:
                moveUp = True
        return moveDown, moveUp, moveLeft, moveRight



##def checker(array):
##  ##  check first value of each part of array (all numbers)
##  ##  compare it to progress
##  ##  if equal to or less than, cycle through rest of that part of array.
##  ##  if greater than, then ignore.
##  ##  e.g: progress = 49, NPC1 will still be on text "0", NPC2 will now be on "33" and NPC3 will be on "0"
##  
##        placeholderList = []
##  
##        for x in range(len(array)):
##                if array[x][0] <= progress:
##                        del placeholderList[0:]
##                        placeholderList.append(array[x][1:])
##        for x in range(len(placeholderList)):
##                passMe = placeholderList[x]
##                print (passMe)
##                npc.interact(passMe)


player = Player() #instance of Player()

playerx, playery, playerwidth, playerheight= player.draw(screen) # gets the players coordinates and measurements

clock = pygame.time.Clock() #instance of the Clock() from the pygame module that specifies fps

personText = ("hello","hi","bye") #some placeholder text
lizardText = ("IM A LIZARD, IM A WIZARD,","IM THE LIZARD WIZARD!")

person1 = NPC("talkToThis.png",100, 200, personText) #instance of NPC(), an entity
lizard = NPC("lizardWizard.png", 300, 250, lizardText)
#npc = NPC("test.png",0, 0) #another NPC() entity

def setup(text): #if an NPC says more than one line of text, this makes sure that they can all be said in succession
        for x in range(len(text)):
                passtext = text[x]
                interact(passtext)


boarderX = player.outX() #code for assigning window boarders
boarderY = player.outY()
##print (boarderX, boarderY) #making sure they both returned properly

pygame.display.flip() #paints screen
gameRun = True #allow game events to loop/be carried out more than once



while gameRun: #while game is running:
        ##person1text2 = [[0,"beginng","www","xxdqsd"],[1,"middle","aa"],[2,"end!"]]
        personText = ("hello","hi","bye") #some placeholder text

        playerx, playery, playerwidth, playerheight = player.draw(screen) #gets new player coords
        #print(playerx, playery, playerwidth, playerheight) # prints them for testing reasons
        person1.collide(playerx, playery, playerwidth, playerheight) # runs collision code to check for collision
        lizard.collide(playerx, playery, playerwidth, playerheight)
        #entityUp, entityDown, entityLeft, entityRight = person1.grabValues(playerx, playery)   
        event = pygame.event.poll() #assigns the pygame event code to the variable event
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: #if the "x" is pressed
                pygame.quit() #quit game
                gameRun = False #break the loop.
                quit()
##        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
####                checker(person1text2)
##                setup(personText)




        screen.blit(background, (bgx, bgy)) #draw background colour

        player.draw(screen) #draws player

        person1.spawn(screen) #spawns an NPC entity
        lizard.spawn(screen)

        moveDown, moveUp, moveLeft, moveRight = playerMove(playerx, playery, width, height)
        player.handle_keys(moveUp, moveDown, moveLeft, moveRight) #handle keys

        pygame.display.update() #updates display

        posX = player.outX() # gets player positions
        posY = player.outY()



        clock.tick(60) #clock cycle
```

the error is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\adamh\Desktop\COMP3\iteration1\OVERWORLDalphaVER6.py", line 8, in <module>
    background = pygame.image.load("spacebackground.png").convert()
pygame.error: No video mode has been set
```

so there is an error on the 8th line specifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TURNS OUT I JUST HAD TO PUT THE CODE DEFINING THE SCREEN BEFORE THE CODE LOADING THE BACKGROUND

whoopsies